# How to "not handler" a click from a children element

Tags: jquery

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dpajH/) :

## HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box">
        Content
    </div>
</div>​
```

## CSS:

```
#container
{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:red;
}

#box
{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
​
```

## jQuery :

```
$('#container:not(#box)').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').fadeOut(300);
});​
```

I want to `fadeOut` only clicking on the parent (the red div). If I click on the blue one (the child) nothing should happens. How can I do this with jQuery? tried with `:not` but seems this is not the right solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do it check whether the element the event originated from (`e.target`) is the `#container` (`this`):

```
$('#container').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        $('#container').fadeOut(300);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed putting prevent default into e.target ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the `#box`, the `click` event also registers on the parent `#container` element because the event bubbles up.

There's two ways top-of-head to prevent that.

First is to stop the bubbling from happening. You do that by calling `e.stopPropagation()` on the `#box` click handler. But, of course, you've got no `#box` event handler, so the next one is a bit more attractive.

Second is to check from the `#container` event handler whether or not you're clicking the actual `#container` or some child and that the event just bubbled up. You can do this by inspecting the `e.target` element, and comparing that to `this` in the `#container` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    $('#container').fadeOut(300);
});

$('#box').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```